# wicket authentication / login

Tags: apache, authentication, wicket

I am following this tutorial http://wicket.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/template-for-building-authenticated-webapplication/ in order to learn how to make login and authentication using wicket.
My question/problem is that my login area is on the header and therefor one can login on every page.

If my application class should inherit AuthenticatedWebApplication, then I must override getSignInPageClass method. What page class should I provide?

Is there any other best tutorial to add authentication using wicket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sign in page is displayed when the user attempts to access a `Page` or other component which requires authorization to create. If your application allows login on every page, then none of your pages require authorization, and the sign in page will never be displayed. I suggest you set it to the home page.

As all your pages are visible, you can't use the `@AuthorizeInstantiation` annotation on your page classes. Instead, you must control visibility of components within the page using the `RENDER` action instead. For example,

```
  MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.authorize(mycomponent, RENDER, "SYSADMIN");
```

The only example I can find is at [wicketstuff.org](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/authorization/).